# Recursive linked list reversal

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

This code is from [this site.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/)

```
void recursiveReverse(struct Node** head_ref)
{
    struct Node* first;
    struct Node* rest;

    /* empty list */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
       return;   

    /* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
    first = *head_ref;  
    rest  = first->next;

    /* List has only one node */
    if (rest == NULL)
       return;   

    /* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
    recursiveReverse(&rest);
    first->next->next  = first;  

    /* tricky step -- see the diagram */
    first->next  = NULL;          

    /* fix the head pointer */
    *head_ref = rest;              
}
```

I dont understand why after the last recursive call the value of rest remains the same? I understand *recursiveReverse(&rest)* is passing the actual address of rest,but isn't this address being taken by head_ref only? Which would mean that every recursive call has its own local copy of first and rest, and so ***head_ref = rest** shouldn't work because the value of rest would keep changing.

Where is my understanding going wrong?

Edit : Adding some of my scribbles.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be missing that `*head_ref = rest;` changes the value of `rest` in the previous loop (i.e. the loop you are returning to). So in this way the address of the last node (your 106) propagates to the top and eventually changes the head pointer

Comment: @4386427 I think I understand what you are saying. But I dont understand why `*head_ref = rest;` changes the value of `rest` in the previous loop. Why should that happen?

Comment: @momo It is logic of recursion, save position in every recursive call unitl hit base case. After hit, go back until from where you commence calling(including)

Comment: @momo Because you passed `&rest` so `head_ref` is a pointer to `rest` of the previous step and consequently `*head_ref = ...` changes the value of `rest` in the previous step.

Comment: @4386427 thanks a lot, I see it now. `head_ref` is a pointer to `rest` is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont understand why after the last recursive call the value of rest
>   remains the same?

It hits base case of the recursive call and immediately returns.

```
 /* List has only one node */
    if (rest == NULL)
       return;
```

> Every recursive call has its own local copy of first and rest?

Yes, exactly. [See how it works.](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/recursion/recursion-and-backtracking/tutorial/)

> `*head_ref = rest` shouldn't work because the value of rest would keep changing.

No. It eventually points to last element of the linked list which will be first element I mean right-most node(in unchanged list) will be pointed to.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still confused at the third point in your answer. After it hits the base case, *head_ref = 106 (according to my assumptions). Now when it goes back to the calling function, isnt the value of rest in this function 104,which would make *head_ref = 104 and so on?

Comment: Think that the list consists of **102->104->106->NULL**,  `*head_ref` points to `102`, in next recursion call points to `104` in next call `106`. **Not** `NULL` because It has been already returned thanks to the base case. Eventually `*head_ref` is pointer to **106**  @momo